# How do I stop google sheets reassigning formulae values on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets

My issue is as follows:

I have formsite automatically adding rows into a workbook in Google Sheets.  Another sheet formats the data for some data capturers to just do a copy and paste into another programme.  My issue is that the mapping seems to go haywire every time formsite adds another row.

For example:
If column a on the copy sheet has

=formsitesheet!a1

=formsitesheet!a2

=formsitesheet!a3

When formsite adds a row instead of the values on the  just updating it changes it to
=formsitesheet!a2

=formsitesheet!a3

=formsitesheet!a4

Is there anyway to change this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code so we can see where the issue is? Also why do you add a row instead of just adding values?

Comment: The extent  of the code is as above, just makignt he cell on one sheet equal the other.  The adding of the row is done by formsite- as a form is filled in it adds a new row for that form's responses.  Its automated site functionality and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround. Use INDIRECT() with ROW()

```
=INDIRECT("'formsitesheet'!A"&ROW(A1))
```

Or

```
=INDIRECT("'formsitesheet'!A"&ROW(A1)+X)
```

Where X is your offset.

Hope this helps