# How do i stop google sheets skipping a row with my formula when a new answer is entered?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Every time a new row of answers is added the formula on another shit will skip the already referenced rows where the new data has just been added.

If i manually drag it down across a number of fields it updates properly and shows the correct number. However if i already have it in those fields when an answer from my google form is entered instead of it updating to show the correct number it stays as 'False' , as it would do when referencing a blank field, and the field reference goes up by one skipping the field it was already referencing.

I've tried absolute referencing with "$b2" and moved it to different positions however it still skips the row it was meant to be referencing. Any idea on how to stop this. Code is below-

---

```
=IF('Form Responses 1'!B$16 = "dog","1",IF('Form Responses 1'!B$16="Cat","2",IF('Form Responses 1'!B$16="Frog","3",IF('Form Responses 1'!B$16="Bird","4"))))
```

---

Essentially there are three columns, Timestamp, Pick a word and email. Those are populated automatically by the google form in to the sheet "Form Responses 1". The column i'm working with is B which is Pick a word. If that cell equals a certain word the corresponding number is outputted in the field with the formula in it. When new data is entered in to B16 for example on Form Responses the formula on the other sheet will change B16 to B17 and skip that row.

Any help is appreciated and I've got a fair understanding of the formulas so don't worry about going in to too much detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640727/how-do-i-stop-google-sheets-reassigning-formulae-values-on-another-sheet).
The workaround is to use INDIRECT() with ROW()

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A16)) = "dog","1",IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A16))="Cat","2",IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A16))="Frog","3",IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A16))="Bird","4"))))
```

Or

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A1)+X) = "dog","1",IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A1)+X)="Cat","2",IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A1)+X)="Frog","3",IF(INDIRECT("'Form Responses 1'!B"&Row(A1)+X)="Bird","4"))))
```

Where X is your offset.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Not entirely crucial but i was just wondering why it's A16 and not B16. Is this referencing a field and then INDIRECT takes the data from the cell next to it, or by however many X is?

Comment: In this case it does not matter whether you use A or B as you are pulling the row. **Row(A1)** is the same as **Row(B1)** and **Row(C1)** and etc.

Comment: If you have a look, I wrote "'Form Responses 1'! **B** "&Row(A16) That is where you define the column for the form sheet.